# I am student and I am forced to write a school board project on magic will this make me a kafir?

Tags: sihr

Assalam alaikum 
I am a student and I am forced to write a school board project on magic will this make me a kafir ?

Comment: Welcome to Islam SE. Questions are expected to be specific, on topic, and with some research done prior to asking. Please refer to [ask], and take a [tour] in our [help]. What do you plan to have as content in this project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it won't, it's the same as writing about Worshiping statues, Adultery, ...
writing about what you don't believe in doesn't make you kafir.

What makes you a Kafir however is breaking the first of the 5 principles Islam is built on (breaking the other 4 makes you a faasiq), here they are:

1. Admitting that Allah is the only God and Mohammad is his last messenger.
2. Praying.
3. Giving charity to the poor.
4. Fasting Ramadan.
5. Visiting Mecca and doing Hajj (optional; only if you have enough money and time)

(As said by the Prophet peace be upon him in Hadith 3 - Al bukhary)

Comment: Salam breaking other than the point no 1 would not make you kafir instead Faasiq.

Comment: Thanks Faqirah you are right, I will edit my answer.